# Google calendar add events stopped working

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I have a problem with Google Calendar that I am unable to resolve. Here is the scenario: I had implemented it successfully using JavaScript as described in [the quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php)

Now it just stopped working without changing anything.

Here is the code of my quickstart.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Say hello using the People API</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
</head>
<body>
<p>Say hello using the People API.</p>

<!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
<button id="authorize-button" style="display: none;">Autoriser </button>
<button id="signout-button" style="display: none;">se deconecter</button>

<div id="content"></div>
<pre id="output"></pre>
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log('im execusted');
    var dateaud = localStorage.getItem("date1")
    var jDate = new Date(dateaud);
    var nd = jDate.toISOString();
    var numdossier = localStorage.getItem("casenumber");
    var notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
    var summary = numdossier + ' ' +notes ;

    // Enter an API key from the Google API Console:
    //   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_
    var apiKey = 'mykey';
    // cette clé est dispo via creer api key
    // Enter a client ID for a web application from the Google API Console:
    //   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_
    // In your API Console project, add a JavaScript origin that corresponds
    //   to the domain where you will be running the script.
    var clientId = 'myclientid';
    // Enter one or more authorization scopes. Refer to the documentation for
    // the API or https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes
    // for details.
    var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';
    var auth2; // The Sign-In object.
    var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
    var signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout-button');
    function handleClientLoad() {
        // Load the API client and auth library
        gapi.load('client:auth2', initAuth);
    }
    function initAuth() {
        gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
        gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: clientId,
            scope: scopes
        }).then(function () {
            auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
            // Listen for sign-in state changes.
            auth2.isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);
            // Handle the initial sign-in state.
            updateSigninStatus(auth2.isSignedIn.get());
            authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
            signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
        });
    }
    function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
            authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
            signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
            makeApiCall();
        } else {
            authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
            signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    function handleAuthClick(event) {
        auth2.signIn();
    }
    function handleSignoutClick(event) {
        auth2.signOut();
    }
    // Load the API and make an API call.  Display the results on the screen.
    function makeApiCall() {
        gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {
            var event = {
                'summary': summary,
                'description': notes,
                'start': {
                    'dateTime': nd,
                    'timeZone': 'Africa/Casablanca'
                },
                'end': {
                    'dateTime': nd,
                    'timeZone': 'Africa/Casablanca'
                }
            };

            var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
                'calendarId': 'primary',
                'resource': event
            });

            request.execute(function(event) {
                alert(nd);
                appendPre('événement crée avec succée .: ' + event.htmlLink);
            });

        });
    }
    function appendPre(message) {
        var pre = document.getElementById('output');
        var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
        pre.appendChild(textContent);
    }
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I call this URL, filling the parameters out correctly for my event using this code:

```
<script>
function addcal(){
    var date1=document.getElementById('date1').value;
    var casenumber=document.getElementById("casenumber").innerText;
    var notes=document.getElementById("notes").value;
    var resultat=document.getElementById('resultat');
    localStorage.setItem('date1', date1);
    localStorage.setItem('casenumber', casenumber);
    localStorage.setItem('notes', notes);
    localStorage.setItem('resultat', resultat);

    window.open('http://mywebsie.com/quickstart.html', 'newwindow', 'width=600, height=400');
}
</script>
```

I get a blank page, with no HTML code in it when showing source code. There are no JavaScript errors.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: "now it just stopped woring without changing any thing". This is not how computers work. _Something_ has changed. Might not be the code, might be the operating environment or other settings.

Comment: ADyson , i compleetly agree with you , i'v just tested it on localhot using mamp and it work as it should , im also facing issue in website in the same dedicated server where the server is serving old javascript files, this is driving me crazy

Comment: Ok well there's not a lot we can do to help you just from the code - if it is shown to work on one environment but not another you just have to start playing spot the difference with relevant features and settings between the two. P.S. If the server is serving old JS files...are you sure it's the server, and not just your browser needing its cache refreshed? Or maybe the server has a cache wrongly configured.

Comment: i resolved the caching issue by desabling all kind of cach using .htacess
but the above html page is not loading and tried to run the above html script in another server and it worked 
now i cannot figure the source of the issue . i checked all the logs for that domain and moved the file in another domaine in the same server : and the behaviour is the same so im assuming it's a globale issue in my server ( i have an OVH dedicated server ). another thing that i do is when i remove the javascript from the html page it work and show the html content

Comment: What about js errors or clues in the console and network tools when the page is loading?

Comment: there was no errors just nothing and when viewing source code of the html page it show nothing just blanc .

Answer (score 0):

good news

the issues was coming from nginx , on the server it's set as a proxy to apache , so desabling it solved my issue.

[image]